# What is the font size if it is defined as 20px/26px?

Tags: css

Just came across the following 20px/26px value in a codebase I am working with. Has anyone ever seen this before and know it's purpose? In chrome it renders using the later px value (26px)

```
#action {
 font: normal 20px/26px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: I swear I can upon a same/similar question that received 1013 upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

This syntax specifies both the `font-size` followed by the `line-height`.
See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font#Syntax).

Answer (score 2):

20px is the `font-size`, 26px is the `line-height`.